# Compact formula for the Fourier transform of $x^n$ exists?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Is it possible to derive a compact formula for the Fourier transform of $f(x)=x^n$ given by $$\tilde{f}(k)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x^n e^{ikx}dx$$ (where $x$ is a real variable and $n$ is a positive or negative integer or zero) which shows the sigularities explicitly for certain values of $n$?

Comment: $x\mapsto x^n$ is not in $L^1(\mathbb R)$ for any $n$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch What about this? [Computing Fourier transform of power law](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2173780/computing-fourier-transform-of-power-law)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the formal computations are indicated in the link by mithusengupta123 [Computing Fourier transform of power law](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2173780/computing-fourier-transform-of-power-law)

However, as mentioned by Maximilian Janisch , $x^n$ is not an $L^1$ function, so in general you will need the Theory of Distributions to define the Fourier transform on these generalization of functions. A distributions $f$ is defined as linear forms on smooth and compactly supported functions $\varphi ∈ C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$, so that instead of looking to $f(x)$ you look at $\langle f,\varphi\rangle$ which if $f$ is a usual fonction will give
$$
\langle f,\varphi\rangle := \int_{-\infty}^∞  f(x)\,\varphi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.
$$
Two distributions $f$ and $g$ are equal when for every $\varphi ∈ C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$,
$$
\langle f,\varphi\rangle = \langle g,\varphi\rangle.
$$
(and this is compatible with locally integrable functions: if two locally integrable functions $f$ and $g$ are equal in the above sense, then they are equal almost everywhere).

For example, if $f=x^n$, then 
$$
\langle f,\varphi\rangle := \int_{-\infty}^∞  x^n\,\varphi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.
$$
But there are other distributions that are not functions, such that the Dirac delta measure $\delta_0$. This distribution is defined by
$$
\langle\delta_0,\varphi\rangle = \varphi(0).
$$
(In particular $∫\delta_0(\mathrm{d}x) = \langle\delta_0,1\rangle =1$)

With this theory, you get that the Fourier transform of $x^n$ when $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is given by
$$
\mathcal{F}(x^n) = 2π i^n \delta^{(n)}_0,
$$
where $\delta^{(n)}_0$ is the $n^{th}$ derivative of the Dirac delta measure. When $n<0$, then you will find
$$
\mathcal{F}(x^n) = i\pi \frac{(ix)^{|n|-1}}{(|n|-1)!} \mathrm{sign}(x).
$$
(This one is in particular a function in the usual sense.)

To prove that, you can start with the case $n=0$ which is given by the Fourier inversion theorem, and then take the derivatives/antiderivatives of the identity obtained to get the others identities (the derivative in the sense of distribution being defined by $\langle f',\varphi\rangle := -\langle f,\varphi'\rangle$).