# Fourier transform of a power law distribution

Tags: fourier-transform, gamma-function

For application purposes, I would like to compute the Fourier transform of a power law distribution,
$$f(t) = b a^b (a + t)^{-b-1}, \qquad a, b, t > 0,$$
which is the integral given by
\begin{align}
\tilde f(\xi) &= b a^b \int_0^{+\infty} (a+t)^{-b-1} e^{-i \xi t} \mathrm{d}t\\
&= b e^{i \xi a} \int_1^{+\infty} u^{-b-1}e^{-i \xi a u} \mathrm{d}u.
\end{align}
Note that the Fourier transform is computed on $[0, +\infty]$ specifically, as $f(t) = 0$ for all $t < 0$.

This problem can be reduced to finding a good approximation for the incomplete Gamma function with pure imaginary argument (see below):
$$\Gamma(\nu, ix) = \int_1^{+\infty} t^{\nu - 1} e^{-i x t} \mathrm{d}t,\qquad 0 < \nu < 1.$$

So I'm looking to either find an explicit formulation or an approximation for the Fourier transform of the power-law distribution, or for the incomplete Gamma function with pure imaginary argument.
Ideally, I would like this Fourier transform to be easy to calculate in C++, as it is the programming language I am currently using for a statistical package I am developing (so any answer involving existing C++ libraries is welcome!).

---

**What I have achieved so far:** when $b$ is an integer, using successive integrations by part, I come up with:
$$\tilde f(\xi) = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{b-1} \frac{(-i \xi a)^k}{(b-1)\cdots(b-k)} + \frac{(-i \xi a)^b}{(b-1)!} e^{i \xi a} E_1(i \xi a),\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
where $E_1(z)$ denotes the exponential integral
$$E_1(z) = \int_1^{+\infty} t^{-1}e^{- tz} \mathrm{d}t.$$
It turns out the exponential integral with pure imaginary argument can be related to the trigonometric integrals $\mathrm{Si}$ and $\mathrm{Ci}$ by the relation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral):
$$E_1(ix) = i \left[ -\frac{1}{2} \pi + \mathrm{Si}(x) \right] - \mathrm{Ci}(x), \qquad x > 0,$$
and that $\mathrm{Si}$ and $\mathrm{Ci}$ have readily available Padé approximants (*i.e.* can be approximated by rational functions) which are accurate to $10^{-16}$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral).
These steps allow fast computation of the Fourier transform of the power law distribution, provided that $b$ is an integer.

**What I struggle with:** when $b$ is not an integer, with similar successive integrations by part than before, I end up with $\Gamma(b - \lfloor b \rfloor, i \xi a)$ instead of $E_1(i \xi a)$ in \eqref{eq1}, where $\Gamma(\nu, z)$ is the incomplete Gamma function:
$$\Gamma(\nu, z) = \int_1^{+\infty} t^{\nu - 1} e^{-z t} \mathrm{d}t,\qquad 0 < \nu < 1.$$
However, I have not found any explicit method to calculate a good approximation of the incomplete Gamma function for $z$ pure imaginary: the C++ libraries I found only work for real arguments, and I could not find good approximations like the ones I did for the exponential integral.

Another stackexchange post ([Computing Fourier transform of power law](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2173780/computing-fourier-transform-of-power-law)) has already discussed this problem, but with a symmetric power-law; I suspect the symmetry facilitates the resolution in this case.

Using the residue theorem, I tried relating $\Gamma(\nu, ix)$ to $\Gamma(\nu, x)$, but this leaves me with an intractable integral along a quarter circle between the real and the imaginary axis; something along the line of
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} e^{i\theta \nu} e^{-\cos \theta - i \sin \theta} \mathrm{d}\theta.$$

**Ending thoughts:** Since the power-law distribution is quite a common function to study, I am surprised that I was not able to find an explicit formulation, or at least an approximation method for its Fourier transform. I am sure that I missed a seminal work on this matter, and if one indeed exists, I would be grateful if you could direct me to it.

Comment: It seems that your question reduces down to finding a computational method for approximating the incomplete gamma function.  You might edit the question to make that more obvious.

Answer (score 2):

It's a strange thing to take a Fourier transform of as it's not really periodic. But perhaps it is a characteristic function or similar.

The Mathematica Command `FourierTransform[b a^b (a+t)^(-b-1),t,x]` gives the output
$$
\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} b \left(-\frac{1}{a}\right)^{-b} \csc (\pi  b) |
    x| ^{b-1} }{\Gamma (b+1)} \left(\left(-\frac{1}{a}\right)^b a^b \left(-| x|  \cos \left(a |
    x| +\frac{\pi  b}{2}\right)+i x \sin \left(a | x| +\frac{\pi
    b}{2}\right)\right)+i x \sin \left(\frac{\pi  b}{2}-a | x| \right)+| x|
    \cos \left(\frac{\pi  b}{2}-a | x| \right)\right)
$$
which seems to be composed of standard library functions.

This simplifies down to
$$
\frac{i \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} a^b (x-| x| ) | x| ^{b-1} e^{i a | x| -\frac{i
    \pi  b}{2}}}{\Gamma (b)}
$$
with $a,b>0$. Let me know if this is not useful, or not what you were after.

Comment: I think the function ```FourierTransform``` in Mathematica computes the transform on $[-\infty, +\infty]$, while in my case, $f(t) = 0$ for $t < 0$.
By the way, doesn't $x - |x|$ reduce to $0$ for $x > 0$, or does $|\cdot|$ means something else here?