# Fourier transform of function in $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: fourier-transform

What is the Fourier transform of $f(x)=\frac{1}{|x|^{\alpha}}$ ? s.t $0<\alpha<n$ and $|x|=||x||_2$

I tried but with no result..  can you give me a hint?

Comment: Please attach your progress on the question. It allows us to help you better. Pardon my grammar :)

Comment: Using rotation invariance and homogeneity could help (but it is not sufficient)

Comment: @RomulusAugustulus sry but i didnt understand...some help pls or some link pls

Comment: @user79161 i tried but i had no result... so my progress does not benefit

Comment: You can prove that the Fourier transform of a distribution invariant by rotation is rotation invariant, and that the Fourier transform of a homogeneous distribuzione is homogeneous (with a different degree of homogeneity). So your Fourier transform must be of the form $\frac{C}{|x|^{\beta}}$ with $\beta$ easily computable. However to compute $C$ you can't no more use symmetries

Comment: @RomulusAugustulus okay thank i'll try. .. i have another question if I have $u \in H^s(\mathbb{R^n})$ and here we are taking the theorem of schwartz space... so my dr. put the fourier of the derivative of u as $FD^su=|2\pi\xi|^sFu$ , so how! Coz I know it should be as if $FD^2u=(2i\pi\xi)^2Fu$ and not as a norm or absolute value!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Computing Fourier transform of power law](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2173780/computing-fourier-transform-of-power-law)

Comment: @Iridescent Yes it might I'll see it. But how did $e^{-2\pi i k \cdot x}$  become $e^{-2\pi i \lvert k \rvert r \cos{\theta}}$!!